# Exam question, complicated chain rule

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have this old exam question that I don't understand.

Calculate $\frac{d}{dt}ln(x^2+y^2)$ where $x=e^t+e^{-t}$ and $y=e^t-e^{-t}$. Write the answer in x and y's.

The solution given does the following:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=e^t-e^{-t}=y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=e^t+e^{-t}=x$$

then use the chain rule to:

$$\frac{d}{dt}ln(x^2+y^2)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}ln(x^2+y^2)\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}ln(x^2+y^2)\frac{dy}{dt}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}*2x*y+\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}*2y*x=\frac{4xy}{x^2+y^2}$$

Question:

How does the teacher do that chain rule step? I would really need a step by step explanation how it's made. I guess I don't understand how dt relates to dx and dy.

Thank you.

EDIT: Updated with last $\frac{dy}{dt}$term that the teacher had left out of the solution sheet.

Comment: I think you left $\dfrac {dy}{dt}$ out of the second term when showing the chain rule applied to this function. $$\frac{d}{dt}ln(x^2+y^2)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\ln(x^2+y^2)\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\ln(x^2+y^2)\frac{dy}{dt}$$You do include it when you then evaluate.

Comment: That mean the teacher forgot that in the solution, and it makes much more sense. Would still want an explanation on how to think on these matters.

Comment: Is it the first equality in your displayed equation that is giving you trouble or subsequent ones?

Comment: @JohnD The first part where he splits up d/dt in parts.

Comment: Question updated with the last term added, as per comment by @amWhy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having trouble with the concept of a [total derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) of a function of several variables. Consider $f=f(x,y)$ where $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$. Then $${d\over dt}f(x,y)={\partial f\over \partial x}\cdot {dx\over dt}+{\partial f\over \partial y}\cdot {dy\over dt}.$$

Here, $f(x,y)=\ln(x^2+y^2)$ with $x=e^t-e^{-t}$ and $y=e^t+e^{-t}$. Thus, 
\begin{align}
{d\over dt}(\ln(x^2+y^2))
&={\partial f\over \partial x}\cdot {dx\over dt}+{\partial f\over \partial y}\cdot {dy\over dt}\\
&={1\over x^2+y^2}\cdot 2x\cdot (e^t+e^{-t})+{1\over x^2+y^2}\cdot 2y\cdot (e^t-e^{-t})\\
&={1\over x^2+y^2}\cdot 2x\cdot y+{1\over x^2+y^2}\cdot 2y\cdot x\\
&={4xy\over x^2+y^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: Like a boss! Thank you John!

Answer (score 1):

(S)He's using the multivariable chain rule that usually written as

$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{d x}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{d y}{dt}.
$$

Here $f$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, and $x$ and $y$ are both functions of $t$. The terms $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ by "ignoring" the fact that $x$ and $y$ are functions of $t$ and computing regular old partial derivatives.

In your case $f(x,y) = \ln(x^2+y^2)$. To compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, you treat $y$ as a constant and differentiate with respect to $x$ using the single-variable chain rule

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\ln(x^2+y^2) = \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2},
$$

and similarly you compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ in the same manner (treating $x$ as fixed and applying the single-variable chain rule for $y$)

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}.
$$

Now onto computing $dx/dt$ and $dy/dt$. Since $x = e^t + e^{-t}$ and $y = e^t - e^{-t}$ are single variable functions of $t$, you compute these just like you would in single variable calculus:

\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt}(e^t + e^{-t}) = e^t - e^{-t} = y\\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= \frac{d}{dt}(e^t - e^{-t}) = e^t + e^{-t} = x.
\end{align*}

Now substitute in the first formula I mentioned above to conclude

$$
\frac{df}{dt} = \left(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}\right)y + \left(\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}\right)x.
$$

Comment: You both gave the same correct and excellent answers, John were just a little bit faster (and slightly less thorough ;). Thank you!

Comment: @Mattis: Happy to help! `:)`